# How to use VBA in MS Office 2003 to add members to a Exchange distribution list

Tags: vba, outlook, exchange-server

My company is using Office 2003. I want to programmatically add members to a distribution list in the GAD ("Global Address Book") on an exchange server.  VBA would be most convenient, but anything will do.  I am the owner of the address book, so permissions hopefully will not be an issues.

Everything I have seen details either how to deal with distribution lists in one's local Contacts folder (NOT what I am looking for), or uses features in Office 2010 which were not available in 2003.

Comment: Just looking at it now.  Will try it next week.  Thanks for info.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to test this so please let us know if it works.

Replace "My GAL DistList Name" with the name of the distribution list as it appears in your address book. And the last line of code would obviously need to be updated with the contact info you want to add to the DL.

```
Sub AddtoDL()

  Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
  Dim al As Outlook.AddressList
  Dim aes As Outlook.AddressEntries
  Dim ae As Outlook.AddressEntry
  Dim newae As Outlook.AddressEntry

  Set ns = session
  Set al = ns.AddressLists("Global Address List")
  Set aes = al.AddressEntries
  Set ae = aes.item("My GAL DistList Name")

  Set newae = ae.Members.Add("SMTP", "Jimmy Pena", "jp@somewhere.com")

End Sub
```

(partially sourced from http://oreilly.com/catalog/cdomapi/chapter/ch07.html)